# How do I make the font change for a specific tag? (html)

Tags: html

so I am about to make a kick start on a new website, and have a lot of `<p>` tags. I want to change the font to Verdana, but I don't want to have to go and manually add a bunch of `<style>` tags. Is there any way to change the entire font of all text with just a few lines of code?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

To set a font for every `p` element can be achieved using one style directive:

```
<style>
p {
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly and is going to save me a lot of time :)

Comment: Why this works, how CSS can be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/First_steps/Getting_started